# Calendar alerts stopped working after upgrading my Galaxy S3 to 4.3

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3, calendar, 4.3-jelly-bean, alerts

I recently upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S3 to Android 4.3. Now my calendar alerts don't pop up anymore.

Any ideas on how to get my calendar alerts working again?